# how to uninstall power designer 16 plugin from eclipse ide juno release

Tags: eclipse, plugins, uninstallation, powerdesigner

I've been trying to uninstall the plugin of power designer 16 (sybase product) from my Eclipse IDE but couldn't find a way to do that. I've checked the about-eclipse > installation details stuff, but power-designer ins't listed in the installed plugins list though all its components are shown in the installed software category (though no option to uninstall them).

I'm also looking for a solution that will remove the power designer perspective that got added as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check in the Eclipse's install folder manually for the plugin's files :

Eclipse > plugins or Eclipse > features

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling/disabling plugins in Eclipse is a bit tricky. I described it once in my blog: http://www.asgarli.net/2011/05/uninstalling-eclipse-plugins-from.html

Comment: thx a lot for the quick answer Elchin, as i said i already tried all the stuff in the help > installation details stuff, also tried reverting to a previous install, but the power designer components are still there, didn't get removed. i'm clueless that's why i asked here to see if there's a different way to solve this.

p.s: thx to the guy who stupidly made the -1 on my question.

Comment: have you also tried removing installation configurations? Those are steps 6 and 7 that I wrote.

Comment: I did try that as well. Thing is the Power Designer's components aren't displayed in the list containing delete revert options but they do in the lists where i've no editing options. It's very weird, Sybase not letting users delete its plugin :/

Comment: Done !! :) , actually i went again to check the eclipse's install files, and found a file in the links folder concerning powerdesigner. And in PowerDesigner, i noticed there's an environment variable that links Power Designer to Eclipse IDE, so what i did is delete that file then restart Eclipse.
As a result the perspective of Power Designer got removed as well as its configurations options settings panel and all the plugins components. Well it was really weird to uninstall this plugin and i hope this solution will help whoever encounters the same problem. Thanks Elchin for your support :)

Comment: first of all it was me who gave the answer, secondly i can't accept my own answer so decided to give +1 to Elchin just for the reason that he was showing support, and accepted temporarely as an answer to show that the case was done and answered. But that other guy's answer made me check again and verify that it does also provide another way to fix this problem ===> i decided to change answer accept for him. And next time please think twice before writing a nonsense comment.@Elchin, if you open your eyes you'll see who wasn't very nice, me who is still upvoting you or you who did a downvote.

Comment: I suggest you don't get personal - doing it over the internet does not show how brave you are.

Answer (score 0):

In Juno:

Windows>Preferences>Install/Update>Uninstall or Update.

Click on plugins you want to remove and click on uninstall